# Ошибка в хроме: Error in event handler for extension.onRequest: undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Сегодня целый день непонятная и ранее невидимая мной ошибка в хроме -

> Error in event handler for
> extension.onRequest: undefined
>
> ```
> extensions::event_bindings:383
> ```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Что это такое и как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в расширении вашего браузера.
Конструкция **[extension.onRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#event-onRequest)** устарела.
Вместо нее рекомендуется использовать **[runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)**

Отключайте расширения по одному, пока не найдете проблемное.

Comment: @VenZell: Спасибо! Касперский всему виной был..